# Adding multiple features from GDB files using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, file-geodatabase

I tried to add all features from a GDB with PyQGIS.

```
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(r"path.gdb")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

This source code, only add one feature from GDB, but the GDB contains a lot of features.

Any idea, how can I do that?

Comment: A file geodatabase is a container object, not a singleton data source. You would need to list the contents, and iterate that list (which can be multi-level, due to feature datasets).

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the layer (feature class) name in the path string.

```py
layer_name = "countries"
layer = QgsVectorLayer("path.gdb|layername=" + layer_name, "Countries", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```